# SQL query in mariadb

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a task to write a SQL query to find which hospital has the most doctors and for that hospital to show all the patients and dates of their  checkup.
Relations that are involved in my db are next:

- Hospital (HospitalID, Name_of_the_Hospital, Place, Phone number)
- Scheduling_Checkups (Hospital, Doctor, Patient, Date_of_the_checkup)
- Patient (PatientID, Name, Addres, Phone_number)
- Doctor (DoctorID, Name, Speciality)

I tried this:

```
 SELECT 
     hospital.Name,COUNT( Scheduling_Checkups.Doctor) AS 'number'
 FROM 
     hospital 
 JOIN
     Scheduling_Checkups ON hospital.HospitalID = Scheduling_Checkups.Hospital 
 GROUP BY 
     Hospital.Name, Scheduling_Checkups.Doctor 
 ORDER BY 
     number DESC
```

But this returns only total number of the doctors that appeared in table
`Scheduling_Checkups`, and if someone appeared twice, it will return incorrect numbers, for example if it said 9 and I had one doctor who appeared twice in the same hospital, then it would be a wrong answer, correct answer would be 8.

Can anyone give me a point and direction how to answer this.

And the query that I tried only tries to find first part.is at all possible to find the hospital with highest number of doctors employeed and in the same query to show  patients and dates of their checkups for that same hospital

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query result with limit  1 could be the where value for set the hopital you need and the join scheduling and patient

```
    select Patient.*, Scheduling_Checkups.*
    from Scheduling_Checkups 
    INNER JOIN Patient on Scheduling_Checkups.Patient = Patient.PatientID
    where Scheduling_Checkups.Hospital  = (

      SELECT hospital.HospitalID

      FROM hospital 
      join  Scheduling_Checkups ON hospital.HospitalID=   Scheduling_Checkups.Hospital 
      GROUP BY Hospital.HospitalID, Scheduling_Checkups.Doctor 
      ORDER BY  COUNT( Scheduling_Checkups.Doctor) DESC LIMIT 1
    )
```

Comment: Thanks.i think i realised how should i think now to find something like this.